# Realm won't save the variable/object once the application is closed. How do I fix this?

Tags: java, android, database, timer, realm

I already have one Realm object working perfectly fine with the Realm. But, my Points object is not saving. When running the app on the Android emulator, clearing it from recents clears the points variable of the Points class. There is only one instance of Points throughout the entire application. I'll insert code of how I'm using Points below. I've also observed the variable updating in the Realm using Stetho with chrome, so it's definitely saving to the database.

MyApplication class where I initially create the object in Realm:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

static Realm realm;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Realm.init(this);

    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name("chargerpoints.realm")
            .schemaVersion(1)
            .build();

    realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    Points pts = realm.where(Points.class).findFirst();

    if(pts == null) {
        Points myPoints = new Points();
        myPoints.setId(1);
        myPoints.setPts(0);
        realm.beginTransaction();
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(myPoints);
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }
```

MainActivity where I increment the points integer variable of myPoints object using a timer:

```
static int points;

Points myPoints;

Context context = this;

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

private Timer timer;
private TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(hours > 7 && hours < 15){
            KeyguardManager myKM = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            if (myKM.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
                points++;
            } else {
                realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                myPoints = realm.where(Points.class).findFirst();
                realm.beginTransaction();
                myPoints.setPts(points);
                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(myPoints);
                realm.commitTransaction();
            }
            displayPoints();
        }
    }
};
```

I have basically tried every possible combination and haven't come close to data persistency with the Points class so far. I already have another object working fine with Realm, so its confusing as to why this one wouldn't work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: 1) Don't save your realm variable in a static variable, you can open/close instances as you need them. 2) Don't use the beginTransaction - code - commitTransaction (commitTransaction is missing in your code) structure but rather use `executeTransactionAsync` 3) you first lookup your Realm with a configuration, then immediately you set your Realm instance to `getDefaultInstance` - perhaps you are looking for `setDefaultConfiguration`?

Comment: I have `commitTransaction` in both pieces of code, but I will try out `executeTransactionAsync`. Also, I will try out the `setDefaultConfiguration`. I'll let you know if it works @nbokmans Thanks!

Comment: @nbokmans Unfortunately, these changes don't solve my issue with the points not saving. Do you know why that might be occurring?

Comment: Call `realm.close()` in your timer task. Without closing the Realm instance, the Realm on that thread may stay in an old version of data forever if that thread doesn't have a looper.

Comment: @beeender I tried that but it's still not saving after the app is cleared from recent apps.

Comment: you have both `realm = Realm.getInstance(config);` and `realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();` in the `onCreate`, why?